# Using a solution from a model as an input to another one and Outputting each Solution Separately

Tags: iteration, cplex, opl

I'm solving an optimization problem in which I need the result from one model to be used as a input in another model for 180 iterations. I'm using CPLEX with OPL language without any addon.

I tried to save the values from one model into an Excel file and reading those into the next model but since I'm going to do this 180 times I am worried I will make an error and have to restart or not even know I made an error.

Is it possible to have this run for 180 iterations and input each iteration's solution separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on warmstart for that.

2 simple examples in [easy OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/)

[Warm start from a file](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooreadMST.mod):

```
include "zoo.mod";

    main {
     var filename = "c:/temp/mipstart.mst";
      thisOplModel.generate();
      cplex.readMIPStarts(filename);
      cplex.solve();
      writeln("Objective: " + cplex.getObjValue());
     
    }
```

or [with API](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoowarmstartapi.mod)

```
int nbKids=300;

    // a tuple is like a struct in C, a class in C++ or a record in Pascal
    tuple bus
    {
     key int nbSeats;
     float cost;
    }


    // This is a tuple set
    {bus} pricebuses=...;

    // asserts help make sure data is fine
    assert forall(b in pricebuses) b.nbSeats>0;assert forall(b in pricebuses) b.cost>0;


    // To compute the average cost per kid of each bus
    // you may use OPL modeling language

    float averageCost[b in pricebuses]=b.cost/b.nbSeats;

    // Let us try first with a naïve computation, use the cheapest bus

    float cheapestCostPerKid=min(b in pricebuses) averageCost[b];
    int cheapestBusSize=first({b.nbSeats | b in pricebuses : averageCost[b]==cheapestCostPerKid});
    int nbBusNeeded=ftoi(ceil(nbKids/cheapestBusSize));

    float cost0=item(pricebuses,<cheapestBusSize>).cost*nbBusNeeded;
    execute DISPLAY_Before_SOLVE
    {
      writeln("The naïve cost is ",cost0);
      writeln(nbBusNeeded," buses ",cheapestBusSize, " seats");
      writeln();
    }

    int naiveSolution[b in pricebuses]=
      (b.nbSeats==cheapestBusSize)?nbBusNeeded:0;


    // decision variable array
    dvar int+ nbBus[pricebuses];

    // objective
    minimize
      sum(b in pricebuses) b.cost*nbBus[b];
         
    // constraints
    subject to
    {
      sum(b in pricebuses) b.nbSeats*nbBus[b]>=nbKids;
    }

    float cost=sum(b in pricebuses) b.cost*nbBus[b];
    execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
    {
     writeln("The minimum cost is ",cost);
     for(var b in pricebuses) writeln(nbBus[b]," buses ",b.nbSeats, " seats");

    }


    main
    {
    thisOplModel.generate();
    // Warm start the naïve solution
    cplex.addMIPStart(thisOplModel.nbBus,thisOplModel.naiveSolution);
    cplex.solve();
    thisOplModel.postProcess();
    }
```

Comment: Be aware that if you just use warm-start then CPLEX may choose to ignore some or all of the values in the warm-start solution. If you need the solution from one problem to be fully respected in subsequent problem instances, then you should do that by setting the bounds on your problem variables or by adding constraints to enforce the necessary values from the previous solution,